# How can I via a searchbar navigate my map?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, maps

I asked the wrong question sorry, let me start over.

I have a map and I want to attach it to a searchbar so when you type a country the map goes there.

This is my code:

```
var theSelect = searchBar.ToString(); //my searchbars name

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder ();
        Task<IEnumerable<Position>> result =
            gc.GetPositionsForAddressAsync (theSelect); //i add it here.

        IEnumerable<Position> data = await result;

        foreach (Position p in data) {


            myMap.MapType = MapType.Street; //my map's name
            myMap.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(//add something here?));

        }
```

The best way possible would be if i could filter it so while I type it would be changing automatically without entering "space", just liek this code below but this is with a listview however. Not sure how I would change it though:

```
private  void FilterContacts (string filter)
    {
        EmployeeList.BeginRefresh ();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (filter)) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("if1");
            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems; //listviews name + class
        } else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("else2");
            EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems.Where (x => x.irl1.ToLower ().Contains (filter.ToLower ()));

        }

        EmployeeList.EndRefresh ();
    }
```